# Loading comma separated file into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scopus

I got a comma separated csv file from Scopus. Each row of the file has such a structure:

```
"A, B, C,D","1111;2222;3333;4444;","A,B,C",1111,"ABCDE","XYZ",,,"338","347",,,"11.10000/111-2-642-35236-2_34",Conference Paper,,Scopus,2-s2.0-1243213123
```

Although it is comma separated, in some fields (like the first one) there are internal commas which raise error when I use `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` as pandas cannot distinguish separator commas and non-separator commas. Is there any way that I can load such a csv file into a dataframe?

Comment: "pandas cannot distinguish separator commas and non-separator commas" - that shouldn't happen, unless you mess up on `quotechar`. I can read your line without any errors using `pd.read_csv('a.csv', header=None)`. Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your problem.

Answer (score 1):

if the separator is comma then :

```
df= pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter = ',' , header = None)
```

empty values are considered as NaN

```
         0                     1      2     3         ...                        13  14      15                 16
0  A, B, C,D  1111;2222;3333;4444;  A,B,C  1111        ...          Conference Paper NaN  Scopus  2-s2.0-1243213123
```

Pandas will detect commas as delimiter and no - delimiters like in the string "A,B,C,D"